# Python: How do I save data even when a long running batch process crashes?

Tags: python, batch-processing

I have a long running python batch process that is processing data from a REST API. In case the program crashes or terminates for some reason I want to save info about the position of my last processing so I can restart and resume. I do not want to loose that info (store it on disk and not only in RAM).

How can I handle this if possible with a lightweight solution maybe without a database?

Thanks
Philip

Comment: If there was a way of giving a name to a batch of data you could save each batch in a file with that name. Upon restart the program could list these files and deduce the next file name to start. (You would have to be careful to use a temp name first, then rename to the real batch name after closing the temp file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at the python module 'shelve'.
It allows you to save data on disk and then retrieve it when needed.